# Hiding hosts in Nagios

Tags: monitoring, nagios, network-monitoring, system-monitoring

I would like to monitor a few hundred hosts using Nagios, yet I only want the switch fabric to show up in the statusmap.cgi.  Is there a way to prevent a host from showing up in the status map, yet have it still be monitored?

Comment: A google search shows somebody else asking the question - http://osdir.com/ml/network.nagios.user/2002-09/msg00007.html - but it comes with no answer :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable `hostgroup` we use `'register 0'` in the `config` file. I think the same we can do for Host "NOT SURE".
Here is the way we disable hostgroup:

```
define hostgroup {
    hostgroup_name              Win-servers
    alias                       Win-servers
    members                     localhost
    register                    0
}
```

I suppose similer we can do for host like:

```
define host {
  host_name                     xyz
  use                           check_mk_host
  address                       120.0.0.0
  _TAGS                         cmk-agent prod lan tcp wato /wato/
  _FILENAME                     /wato/hosts.mk
  hostgroups                    check_mk
  alias                         xyz
  register                      0
}
```

Comment: I dont see why this was downvoted, while hidden hostgroups are _NOT_ available in each nagios version or clone it's one of the most elegant ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [NagViz](http://www.nagvis.org/). It's a great tool for Nagios which allows you to visualise exactly what you want and is extremely flexible.

Another great tool to visualise your monitoring hosts/networks is [PHP Weathermap](http://www.network-weathermap.com/)

I am not sure statusmap.cgi is generally  popular.

Nagios CGI documentation is [here](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/cgis.html#statusmap_cgi)

Answer (score 0):

To hide the view of some host group you can comment, in the nagios.cfg file, inside the section "Object configuration file(s)", the line of object configuration file of the group you need to hide.

Eg.:

### Definitions for monitoring the local (Linux) host

#cfg_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/localhost.cfg << Commented line